# How do I debug why xcode won't run my unit tests?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I recently started working on an old ios app which doesn't have unit tests. I am not an ios developer myself. Due to circumstances I feel compelled to start writing unit tests.

App has multiple dependencies added using cocoapods. One of them is a framework which we maintain ourselves.

I am trying to run the dummy testExample that is auto-generated while creating a project. It doesn't have any code.
When I run the test xcode builds & installs the app. App shows the splash screen. But after that nothing happens.
I also tried running the test from command line in case it would print any errors. But it shows
`Testing started for configuration 'Configuration 1'`
and stops.

I have tried all the remedies I could find on stackoverflow and apple's forum. Typical ios project troubleshooting like deleting folders, etc. have also been tried. I am completely stuck without any error message.

I tried running the dummy test in a newly created project on the same xcode & device and it ran.

How can I debug this issue? Is something in the app code stopping the unit tests from running. How can I make sure that all the right checkboxes are checked and the build configs all correct? Is there a comprehensive list somewhere of steps required to set up unit testing?

Xcode version - 13.4.1 Test device - iphone 11, ios version 15.6

Comment: What happens if you add some asserts to the test? For example `XCTAssertTrue(false)`

Comment: No change. `print` statements in `setUp` also don't come up on console. `print` statements in `AppDelegate` too don't show up.

Comment: Update
1. Delete test target.
2. Delete test group
3. Create new test target.
4. Auto generated test runs.
5. Do pod install
6. Test builds but doesn't run.

I noticed a difference between steps 4 & 6 in Project -> Info tab -> Configurations -> Debug -> test target has None initially but changes to Pods-AppNameTests.debug

This seems like a faulty pod set up for test builds to me.